# How to fix: Host name 'repo1.maven.org' does not match the certificate subject provided

Tags: maven, gradle, certificate, hostname, repo

My builds are starting to fail today. Looks like we're still pointing to a deprecated maven repository? How do I update my gradle build without having to override every mavenCentral?!

If I do the follow, then my build works again. But I have so many projects that need to build in Jenkins.

```
repositories{
    mavenCentral(url:'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2')
}
```

Here's the errors we're seeing:

```
> Could not resolve commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6.
  Required by:
      project : > [ snip ]:1.0-SNAPSHOT > net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:1.0.6
   > Could not resolve commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6.
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.pom'.
            > Host name 'repo1.maven.org' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=repo.maven.apache.org, O="Sonatype, Inc", L=Fulton, ST=MD, C=US)
```

TIA!

Piko

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue started today, use https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-2870 for tracking the status.